Django Authentication Timeout Error (H12) on Heroku with MongoDB Atlas
I have a question regarding an issue I'm facing. I built an authentication system in Django and connected it to a MongoDB Atlas database. The website is deployed on Heroku, but I'm encountering a timeout error on Heroku (Error H12). I've already checked the database connection, and it seems to be working. I also changed the timeout duration to 60 and 120 seconds, but neither resolved the issue. What could be causing this error?
ERROR MESSAGE :
heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=XXXX (i changed my host name).herokuapp.com request_id=3f41-4c44-8740-a56e6191eb53 fwd="xx.xx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

I checked the MongoDB Atlas connection, and it appears to be working fine. I also adjusted the timeout settings, increasing the timeout to 60 and 120 seconds, hoping this would resolve the H12 error on Heroku. However, I was expecting the website to load properly without timing out, but the issue persists despite these changes.

Hey, i had to increase timeout too. It was loading properly these days and today all of a sudden started getting 504 from my endpoint. My endpoint is simple just doing a mongoose query. Did you contact support by any chance? Have you seen an enhance in performance in the last couple of hours? I'll keep you posted of my findings.

hi, thought it was my code error, however I will contact with support and I will update here

It got back to normal in my case. Are you still experiencing this issue?

No, still same error
